# MariaDB 11.2 (x64) The TCP Port you selected is already in use

Tags: sql, mariadb

Never ever installed MySQL DB on Windows 10 machine, hence TCP port 3306 should be free.

Tried to install MariaDB 11.2 (x64) for the first time on windows 10 machine, TCP port 3306, and get an error message:

The TCP Port you selected is already in use. Please choose a different port

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I’d start by checking what is using that port - you can use the netstat command to do this e.g. netstat -a -n -p tcp -b

Comment: have used this netstat tool and the port is unused.
Weird problem, since I have never ever installed MySQL or MariaDB on this Windows 10 machine.

Prefer to fix the problem as opposed to ignore it

Comment: I Have finally found the answer.
For some unknown reason, Windows 10 machine had a mysqld.exe running on Port 3306 on a certain PID, even not having any apparent mysql server installed on the machine.

Resolution:
1/ turned off windows firewall
2/ turned off karspersky firewal
3/ have performed the following
Windows – Start and Stop Server _ Open 'Run' Window by using Win key + R.  _ Type 'services.msc' _ Now search for MySQL service based on the version that is installed. _ Click on 'stop', 'start' or 'restart' the service option. _ after have run MariaDB windows setup file and works

Answer (score 0):

I Have finally found the answer.
For some unknown reason, Windows 10 machine had a mysqld.exe running on Port 3306 on a certain PID, even not having any apparent mysql server installed on the machine.
Resolution:
1/ turned off windows firewall
2/ turned off karspersky firewal
3/ have performed the following
Windows – Start and Stop Server _
Open 'Run' Window by using Win key + R. _
Type 'services.msc' _
Now search for MySQL service based on the version that is installed. _
Click on 'stop', the service option. _
after that I have run MariaDB windows setup file and works